# Embedded Linux Training

Tags: linux, training, embedded-systems

I have been working with an old `OS9`(not mac) operating system and I have been trying to get my organization to transition to an embedded `Linux` platform.  We have money in the budget for training and I figure I would take advantage of it.  A secondary impetus would be a good resume addition.

What are some good vendors/bootcamps for Embedded Linux training?

Answer (score 1):

[Linuxfoundation.org - embedded linux development training course](http://training.linuxfoundation.org/courses/linux-developer/embedded-linux-development) and 
other [linux developer training courses](http://training.linuxfoundation.org/courses/linux-developer) offered by the Linux Foundation.

The training from [Free Electrons](http://free-electrons.com/training/embedded-linux/) is also nice.